# Does MySQL have a cryptographically secure random number generator?

Tags: mysql, security, random, cryptography

So far I have been using PHP to create cryptographically secure random values, with [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php). I would like to generate a cryptographically secure token within a stored function, is RAND() what I am looking for, or is it not cryptographically secure?

Comment: i am looking at this exact same issue right now.  i have what i believe are real PRNG in my source language, but think the rand() that is available from stored procedures (to manipulate data created in my source language) is not cryptorandom.  it would definitely say *what* algorithm it used if it was a secure random.  a sha256 of rand() and now() is what people are suggesting.  that's probably not going to do much because there are timestamps everywhere....

Comment: @Rob: Let me know if you find anything. I scrapped the MySQL approach and am passing a cryptographically secure token to MySQL for now.

Comment: i may migrate to re-encrypting outside the database as well.  the application is the only thing with keys at the moment, and it's probably better to keep keys away from database; but i wanted to rotate keys in a transaction.

Comment: This thing returns a double, and look at it's definition.  I'm not sure how to use this as a starting point for a crypto-random function.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/mysys_ssl/my_rnd.cc

sha2(concat(now(),rand()),256) would be giving 2^64 of 2^256 possible values due to returning double if they were all computed at the same value of now().  Secure RNGs are basically CTR ciphers that re-key at about a megabyte, and ensure that there is always enough new entropy being fed in (from hardware if possible).

Comment: solution i am happy with: sha2(concat(rand(),now(),gibberish,id)) ... have the caller supply its own entropy.  rand() adds some number of bits of randomness... probably no more than 32.  now adds maybe a dozen more (attacker can see timestamps). gibberish should be supplied by the caller, and id is unique per call (ie primary key associated with row being altered).  Fortuna CRNG is basically a hash over an incrementing large (secret) iv (or lost key) that changes often (ie: 256 bit input, used for 1MB).  the gibberish would be something like... a string of hex-dice roll outcomes.

Comment: @Rob - maybe this algorithm will give you some inspiration: https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm (see below that page) It's optimized for passwords but I assume you can rework that if it catches your eye.

Comment: @Rob - I don't think the product you linked to works from within a MySQL installation.

Comment: you need to supply MySQL with external randomness.  its random number generator is not going to give you anywhere near 256 bits of entropy.  A good crypto-random number generator is effectively a strong cipher where there is a large key that is intentionally lost.  The point is to take some entropy bits (ie: 256) and stretch it with a cipher.

Comment: @Rob - Dude, sorry, my last comment was meant for Jaiden Snow... I messed that up...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was looking into the same issue. RANDOM_BYTES(len) seems to be the solution that we have been looking for

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes

would use something like HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(length_of_session_cookie))

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way
>   to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between
>   platforms for the same MySQL version.

If developer says that he didn't develop his function to be perfectly random for me it means a function is probably not perfectly random. And for cryptography you want as random as possible.

Comment: the real issue with it is that this is one of those that returns a double from 1 to 0, which can't possibly return more than 64 bits of entropy (which you can mash through a hash to mask the problem as best you can).  I think this is the actual definition:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d52e7c7a1a23424e39273cbb6f5f9d56fda8d1/mysys_ssl/my_rnd.cc