# Does RAND() has low entropy to generate salts?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, encryption, cryptography

I have to encrypt several data in my DB (no password)
I would use a salt to prevent rainbow attack.
I'm generating a salt like that:

```
mysalt = UNHEX(SHA2(RAND(),512))
```

is RAND() (mysql function)  an enough source of entropy? I should have all my salts value different each other, but if my PRNG has too much collision isn't the case. Does it depend from number of records in DB? If it is the case what is the limit with `RAND()`? Which could be a good alternative technique if that above isn't good? Finally is that good to salt passwords too?

Comment: RAND() produces FLOAT output (4 bytes). You want to use SHA-512 (64 bytes). Illogical.

Comment: More suitable is probably [`RANDOM_BYTES(len)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes), s. [Does MySQL have a cryptographically secure random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35880963/9014097).

Comment: @Akina I saw this example for generate a salt in a book.  Your comment makes sense, However I had already thought about, but I had neglected it because it works. I don't know but may be that numbers are automatically converted to strings: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: I don't have any idea with what you mean with "no password" though. Did you want to generate a key instead of a salt maybe?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes passwords haven't to be decrypted, thus for them I'll use an hash function (no AES) and I have specified that before some know-it-all came to tell me: Beware that if the data is the password it is better not to use encryption :)

Comment: @Topaco Thus RANDOM_BYTES() is a TRNG. Awesome!

Comment: @Umbert No it isn't a TRNG is a "true" random number generator, i.e. one that is almost directly fed by an actual entropy source. OpenSSL however providers a DRBG or CSPRNG seeded by  enough entropy, in other words, most of the randomness that you receive is created by a cryptographically secure algorithm. That's OK though, that's what you need.

Comment: You might get better answers to this sort of question on [security.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Uh, no, API related questions belong here, officially at least. Umbert,  note that you may want to look at PBKDF2 or similar **password hashes**. Do not just use a salt and an SHA-256 or another non-password hash to protect your passwords.

Comment: @Umbert - `RANDOM_BYTES()` is a CSPRNG used in cryptography for generating (pseudo) random data (exactly what you need). In the post [What is the difference between TRNG and CSPRNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63555) you can find a nice explanation of a CSPRNG and the difference to a TRNG.

Comment: There may be some confusion caused by wrong terminology. `salt to prevent rainbow attack.. `  Salt and rainbow tables are used with hashed values (or PBKDF). If you are encrypting some data, do you intend to use the *salt* as a KDF salt? Or as a cipher IV? That may be different is RAND is good enough.

Comment: @gusto2  I'm using AES and I will use the salt as key_string (like second parameter in the sql AES_encrypt function). In this case RAND() is good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to encrypt several data in my DB (no password) I would use a salt to prevent rainbow attack.

As already commented, you should use proper terminology to make sure we're talking about the same thing. Based on the comments let's assume you're generating an IV (initialization vector) for a [block mode (cbc, cfb or ofb)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html). The IV is enabling the safe key reuse. Nothing to do with rainbow tables.

```
mysalt = UNHEX(SHA2(RAND(),512))
```

`RAND()` generates a float between 0 and 1. Your function effectively uses the float as a string, so proper notation would be `sha2(convert(RAND(),CHAR),128)`, AES is using 128 bit IV anyway. No reason to generate more.

> is RAND() (mysql function) an enough source of entropy?

Depends on the modes used. Some modes (CTR, CFB) the IV is required to be unique (event a simple counter is good enough), for the CBC and OFB mode the IV needs to be "unpredictable" (stronger term than random).

I am unable to find source state of the RAND() function and then  I am unable to guarantee it cannot be brute-forced (it can be done in case of timestamp-based source for NLFSR PRNG). I'm not really willing to dig into the mysql source code (as far I recall mysql uses the OS rand function, so it will depend on the underlying system, I may be wrong here). So RAND() can be safe to generate the IV for CBC, under assumptions that the initial state is random enough. Seems no-one here is able to confirm nor deny this assumption. Using `RANDOM_BYTES()` it is guaranteed to use a cryptographically secure random source.

> Does it depend from number of records in DB? 
> If it is the case what is the limit with RAND()?

You need a unique combination of the key-iv. The more records you have the higher probability of the value collision. And here we come again with with the initial RAND state size which is system-depended, though in the comment someone claims it's 4 bytes. That's really not too much.

> Which could be a good alternative technique if that above isn't good? 
> Finally is that good to salt passwords too?

As already commented, [RANDOM_BYTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes) are using the random generator from the SSL library, which is required to be cryptographically feasible.